# Responses of machine learning functions?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm

When going through any of the machine learning functions explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html). They all follow the format of cvStatModel.

For example the train function of NormalBayes is achieved by:

```
CvNormalBayesClassifier::train(const Mat& trainData, const Mat& responses, const Mat& varIdx=Mat(), const Mat& sampleIdx=Mat(), bool update=false )
```

The documentation tells you to check out cvStatModel for details on parameters.

What I dont understand is what is `responses` supposed to take? I know that `trainData` is the data we used for training the system using bag of words, but what to place in responses?

In an example on bag of words the responses element was handled as follows:

```
float label=atof(entryPath.filename().c_str());
labels.push_back(label);

NormalBayesClassifier classifier;
classifier.train(trainingData, labels);
```

So here the filenames of the images were converted to doubles and used as the `responses` element.

I don't understand this and am confused by it. Can some one please explain what the `responses` element is supposed to take? and why is `atof` used in the above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those models are supervised machine learning techniques, it means that training the model requires not only the training data (i.e. the vectors of measurements), but also the labels (or continuous values) associated with each sample. For example, if you are trying to detect images containing cats, you have a training set of, say, 500 images not containing cats and 500 containing cats. You compute your descriptors for all 1000 images, and you assign a number to each category (by convention, -1 for "non-cats", 1 for "cats). Then, responses will be a matrix of 1000x1 integers, the first 500 values being -1, while the remaining beeing 1.

In you example, atof is used to convert a directory name to a unique number, representing the category, because training examples are probably sorted by folders (folder cats, dogs, bicycles, etc).